# How to install GNU Assembler

Tags: software-installation, bootloader, assembler

I am trying to write a boot-loader, so I need GNU Assembler. I googled it but didn't find any helpful material. How can I install GNU Assembler (and not GNU Compiler)?

Answer (score 5):

GNU assembler, AKA `as`, is installed by default on Ubuntu. It is in the package `binutils`.

Comment: can you tell me how i can use it?

Comment: Teaching you assembly language is well beyond the scope of a post here.

Comment: any useful link or other material

Comment: `man as` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

**Build from source and use it**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux

# Build.
sudo apt-get build-dep binutils
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
cd binutils-gdb
git checkout binutils-2_31
./configure --target x86_64-elf --prefix "$(pwd)/install"
make -j `nproc`
make install

# Test it out.
cat <<'EOF' > hello.S
.data
    s:
        .ascii "hello world\n"
        len = . - s
.text
    .global _start
    _start:
        mov $4, %eax
        mov $1, %ebx
        mov $s, %ecx
        mov $len, %edx
        int $0x80
        mov $1, %eax
        mov $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
EOF
./install/bin/x86_64-elf-as -o hello.o hello.S
./install/bin/x86_64-elf-ld -o hello hello.o
./hello
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/8b450549cf2482028bf43c94b267fa55d89ea4e6/binutils.sh).

TODO: how to configure `as` specific options? We have used the `./configure` from the `binutils-gdb` top-level, but that contains options from multiple projects such as `gdb` I believe, and not `as` specific ones?

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.